# What is wrong with the view alter?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
ALTER ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY
DEFINER VIEW `patient_dentist` AS

SELECT `patients`.`office_id` AS `office_id`
    ,`patients`.`id` AS `patient_id`
    ,`patients`.`dentist_id` AS `dentist_id`
    ,`patients`.`dentist2_id` AS `dentist2_id`
    ,`patients`.`dentist3_id` AS `dentist3_id`
FROM `patients`
WHERE (
        (`patients`.`dentist_id` IS NOT NULL)
        AND isnull(`patients`.`deleted_at`)
        )

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT `reservations`.`office_id` AS `office_id`
    ,`reservations`.`patient_id` AS `patient_id`
    ,`reservations`.`staff_id` AS `dentist_id`
FROM `reservations`
WHERE (
        (`reservations`.`patient_id` IS NOT NULL)
        AND (`reservations`.`staff_id` IS NOT NULL)
        AND isnull(`reservations`.`deleted_at`)
        );
```

I add two fields in the 'patients' TABLE, the `dentist2_id` and `dentist3_id`.

Answer (score 1):

You should add those columns in both part of the code as UNION requires same number of columns. If you do not have those columns try adding some dummy values

```
ALTER ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY
DEFINER VIEW `patient_dentist` AS

SELECT `patients`.`office_id` AS `office_id`
    ,`patients`.`id` AS `patient_id`
    ,`patients`.`dentist_id` AS `dentist_id`
    ,`patients`.`dentist2_id` AS `dentist2_id`
    ,`patients`.`dentist3_id` AS `dentist3_id`
FROM `patients`
WHERE (
        (`patients`.`dentist_id` IS NOT NULL)
        AND isnull(`patients`.`deleted_at`)
        )

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT `reservations`.`office_id` AS `office_id`
    ,`reservations`.`patient_id` AS `patient_id`
    ,`reservations`.`staff_id` AS `dentist_id`,
    0,
    0
FROM `reservations`
WHERE (
        (`reservations`.`patient_id` IS NOT NULL)
        AND (`reservations`.`staff_id` IS NOT NULL)
        AND isnull(`reservations`.`deleted_at`)
        );
```